# Is a new proposal of generics backward compatible with older versions

Tags: go, generics, design-documents

Among many new things in the recent [proposal about adding generic programming for Golang](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43651#issuecomment-759437603) there is a new keyword `any`

So if my current program has declared a variable named `any` it won't compile.

Comment: It's targeted at Go2, which mean it does not have to be backward-compatible. It's just a proposal right now though, so it's subject to change before release.

Comment: `any` will not  be a keyword. Read the proposal properly, it is predeclared.

Comment: @Adrian "If the proposal is accepted, our goal will be to have a complete, though perhaps not fully optimized, implementation for people to try by the end of the year, perhaps as part of the Go 1.18 betas."

Comment: If it's accepted into a go1.x release, then by definition it's backwards compatible.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. How is it possible? @Volker can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question is downoted and closed. It's a reasonable question to ask. The answer is two fold: first, YES it's backwards compatible -- the proposal says this explicitly. Twice. (https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md#values-of-type-parameters-are-not-boxed). As for the *how does this work with any* question, Volker's answer below addresses that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in the recent proposal about adding generic[s ...] there is a new keyword `any`.

Wrong. `any` will be a predaclared identifier not a keyword.

> So if my current program has declared a variable named any it won't compile.

No, of course not, it will just redeclare `any` in the current scope.

The list of keywords in Go is pretty short, see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords . Keywords are keywords and cannot be used for other things. A predeclared identifier (see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) is not a keyword and can be redeclared.